# Best practice/Storage selection for CQRS/Event sourcing architecture

Tags: architecture, cassandra, redis, apache-kafka, cqrs

**Task.** Build scalable high load application with CQRS/Event sourcing architecture.

Let's assume it's free advert board with lot of online users. So user should be able to:

1. Register/Login
2. Add/Update/Delete advert
3. See the list of adverts
4. Search for adverts
5. Analyze adverts after some time/Reproduce each app state from Event Store.

**My thoughts.**

I would think about using of something like:

1. Cassandra/MongoDB... - Store Events
2. Kafka/Redis/Hazelcast/RabbitMQ... - Event queue
3. Elastic Search + Cache(e.g. Redis) - for View

**Questions.**

1. What's cons/pros of using one against another for each step? Or maybe combine Event Storage with queue (E.g. use Kafka as queue and long term event storage)?
2. Does anyone has proven stack and can share experience for CQRS/Event sourcing architecture ?

Comment: Does `PHP` count?

Comment: Constantin GALBENU, Question isn't related to programming language, it's more about Queue/Storage stack.

Answer (score 1):

For my current project,a web based CRM application, I use the following stack:

1. MongoDB as event store;
2. I don't use an event queue; I don't need one as I use pooling from the event store; every consumer manages it's own state.
3. MongoDB for views.

Comment: It's quite good example, but seems like it's far from being high loaded and I am not sure that it's 100% CQRS architecture since you are creating view each time for user.

Comment: How does "delete" or "update" happens in that case ? Are you checking for corresponding events before reproducing the state?

Comment: It is 100% CQRS + Event sourcing.

Comment: How many instances of MongoDB are you running, how many events/sec and what kind of latency?
Pooling for events is a horrible way to process and react to events.

Comment: @MatijaGobec 12000 events wrote/sec and 35000 events read per second. Pooling is not a horrible way, if you use it for the right reasons. Pooling in microservices is a good way to react to events as the microservice react on its own speed (dictated by the hardware) and the system is very reactive/resilient. If a microservice fails the rest of the system is unaffected.

Answer (score 0):

This is kinda broad question and it boils down to what you are comfortable with regarding technology.

My choice would be:
1. Cassandra (did you even try to scale MongoDB?)
2. Kafka + Redis (Redis if caching is required)
3. Elasticsearch

These 3 technologies can provide you with pretty much everything you need.

Comment: I worked with 4 mongo shards on my previous project, we faced some issues (Row Count, bad sync between DataCenters in case of high latency), but anyway it's quite ok. Now I am not sure do I need Cassandra at all or configured for huge TTL Kafka will be ok as storage and queue...